# Memory efficient way to replace string in Java

Tags: java, regex, memory, jvm, heap-memory

We're about to release a site which displays up to 500 images at a time which are stored on Amazon. Since the urls are stored in our database with "http" instead of "https", I need to substitute the "http" with "https" every time the image url is retrieved. Here's the current code:

```
static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http");

Matcher m = p.matcher(urlSmall);;
String secureUrlSmall = m.replaceFirst("https");
return secureUrlSmall;
```

My concern is that by creating so many String objects I'll eat up Java heap space. Is there a better solution somehow involving StringBuilder, for example?

Comment: where's the difference between using a `StringBuilder` and a `Matcher`? Both build a new `String`. Doesn't matter which one you use, since both will pollute the heap with new `String`-Objects. And I doubt a simple update to the values in the database would be **that** complicated.

Comment: I doubt very much that this matters at all (compared to the rest that is going on with your website, such as talking to the database, or sending HTML to a browser). FWIW, you don't have to involve a pattern matcher, a simple `return urlSmall.replace("http://", "https://");` should do.

Comment: This looks reasonable to me, using a `StringBuilder` would still involve converting to a `String`.

Comment: The presence of a `return` statement indicates that `m` is a *local* variable.  Therefore, the matcher-object will be instantiated, used, and then immediately released, making it available for garbage collection.  The strings, presumably, will also be similarly short-lived.  I see nothing here that might "eat up" heap space.

Comment: Wouldn't make it much more sense to update your urls in the database? Why keep the incorrect url and update at each time in Java?

Comment: @Thilo: Agreed, except for one thing: `replace()` calls `replaceAll()` under the hood, creating new Pattern and Matcher objects every time.  It would actually be more efficient to continue using `replaceFirst()`, but reusing the same Pattern and Matcher objects.

Comment: @AlanMoore. I am shocked. Time to go back to Commons Lang StringUtils.

Comment: @Thilo: you are willing to waste performance by using a method which searches the entire string for all matches when only the first is desired, but are worrying about a temporary object created in the background? You should rethink your priorities…

Comment: @Holger: I said I doubt very much that this matters at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of solutions other than thinking about java string pool maintenance. Since based on expert comments we can't do much about it. Architectural guidance has always been to avoid excessive processing on data by use of proper modelling.

I don't think an improvement is viable in Java, but if I get this problem, I will try the following:

I ask a question to myself- Are these URL's modeled properly? if requirement is to have http or https to be appended to 'Main' part (domain name/full URL) in different cases. I would prefer storing 'Main' part of URL in the database separately and append http/https to them during select. There can be multiple approaches to do this.

If database model can not be changed at this point,
Other way to replace http to https during select query.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex can be relatively expensive. Plain string manipulation can be much faster if that if you call it often enough

```
if (urlSmall.startsWith("http:"))
   return "https:" + urlSmall.substring(5);
if (urlSmall.startSwith("https:"))
   return urlSmall;
// error
```

> My concern is that by creating so many String objects I'll eat up Java heap space.

You will create a lot of garbage doing this, but you will create much more garbage just obtaining the original `urlSmall` from the database.

Unless you are going to cache the database in memory, I would accept that using a database is mostly likely a fast enough rather than as fast as possible solution.

Comment: Using regex with a pre-built `Pattern` isn’t necessarily expensive considering what happens under the hood (the same string concatenation operations than with the manual code), especially when using `Pattern.LITERAL` where appropriate. If you want to beat it, you can omit the temporary `String` object created by `substring`: `return new StringBuilder(urlSmall.length()+1).append("https:") .append(urlSmall, 5, urlSmall.length()).toString();`

Comment: @Holger While a literal pattern is so expensive it still creates a lot of objects you don't need when it is used.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a string pool if you are creating lots of strings. it will help in memory management as u can control maximum number of strings that can be there at a time also they will be used more efficiently as they an be reused when not used.

Comment: Architectural guidance has been to avoid excess of code. As per best programming practices we need to use existing API/Library. In this case it turns out to be in Oracle. More code we write, more bugs and in turn more maintenance it has for all the teams.

Comment: Actually, this might not be a bad idea.  You could create an LRU cache based on [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), with the `http:` URLs as keys and `https:` ones as values.  The `computeIfAbsent()` method could do the `replaceFirst()` to generate the values.  If this is really a problem that needs solving, it would be a good solution.

Comment: A JVM retains as much strings as there are strong references to them. A “string pool” can’t change anything about it, all it would do, is to hold *more* references to otherwise unused strings.